# combine latest is not triggering properly in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I have a behavior subject boolean and it is assigned to an observable. I'm using this observable in a combineLatest. In Chrome and other browsers (Except Firefox and IE) this combine latest is triggering whenever the behavior subject value is changed. In Firefox and IE alone this is intermittently working.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have belongs not to the rxjs but to the functions are used in the code that don't exist in IE and require a polyfill.

For example `Map` `Set` `Array` have methods that aren't present in IE but exist in Edge or Chrome.

If you want to debug it - open developer tools in IE find the error, from the error you can understand which polyfill should be added and then simply update `polyfills.ts` with something like that:

```js
import '@angular/localize/init';
import 'classlist.js';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es7/array';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'url-polyfill';
import 'web-animations-js';
import 'whatwg-fetch';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```